# Fetching videos list from a Youtube playlist through RSS doesn't return more than 15 results

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, rss

I'm using the following API to fetch a list of the videos in a playlist:

```
https://www.youtube.com/feeds/videos.xml?playlist_id=
```

The problem is if the playlist has more than 15 videos, the response is only the first 15. I thought there is a paging algorithm, but there is no `link rel="next"` in the response and appending `?page` to the end of the link returns 404.

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, the [YouTube Data API v2](https://youtube-eng.googleblog.com/2015/04/bye-bye-youtube-data-api-v2.html) call is already deprecated and encourage you to use the  YouTube Data API (v3).

I found in this [thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/youtube/comments/339idg/youtube_just_dropped_its_support_for_rssatom_feeds/) that `https://www.youtube.com/feeds/videos.xml?playlist_id=xxxxx` is only limited to **15** videos or results.

The old API use [`max-results`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_api_query_parameters#max-resultssp) and [`start-index`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_api_query_parameters#start-indexsp) to get more results but it is not working anymore when I try.

If you want more results than 15, I suggest you to use the [`PlaylistItems: list`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list) of the YouTube Data API (v3). It has a parameter [`maxResults`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list#maxResults) that you can set to maximum of 50. To get the another or next 50 results, you can use the parameter [`pageToken`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list#pageToken) for it.

Hope this information helps you.