# How to use YouTube Data API (v3) to get more than 15 videos in an RSS reader (newsboat)?

Tags: google-api, youtube, youtube-api, rss

I was wondering if you could pull more than 15 videos from a youtube channel's RSS feed (I'm using newsboat with a macro to open mpv to play the videos from the links but that's unlikely to make a difference, any RSS reader and media player that can use links should suffice for this). The default URL of `https://www.youtube.com/feeds/videos.xml?channel_id=CHANNELID` only gives the 15 more recent videos. I found this question: [Fetching videos list from a Youtube playlist through RSS doesn't return more than 15 results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42258132/fetching-videos-list-from-a-youtube-playlist-through-rss-doesnt-return-more-tha) and the user KENdi says to use the Google-Data-API (v3) and use the command "PlaylistItems: list" with documentation located here: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list to theoretically pull as many as 50 videos.

I have no idea what is meant by this. How do you actually apply this knowledge in practice? All I have access to is newsboats' ~/.newsboat/urls file to add links with tags to the menu so where would I actually add an implementation of some API call and would it normally give me the link so that I can play it in mpv straight from newsboat?

Comment: It wouldn't normally give you the link formatted for RSS / newsboat. The API returns JSON format data, RSS needs XML formatting. With API you would get a list with the videoID, title, uploaded date, thumbnail image, etc.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what does newsboat show if you enter this URL? (replace the parameters with your desired channel): 
`https://www.scriptbarrel.com/xml.cgi?channel_id=CHANNEL_ID&name=NAME+OF+CHANNEL`

Comment: @Bman70 Yeah, that works in giving me the most recent 50 videos. Thank you very much

Comment: @Bman70 thanks so much for this! I wanted to retrieve all old videos in a channel by RSS